# Using IterableDataset from Pytorch in Huggingface

Tags: huggingface-transformers, pytorch-dataloader

I would like to make training of a gpt2 from scratch on a very specific non-english corpus with Hugging Face. I managed to "train" a tokenizer. I managed to create a simplified version of gpt2 with less embedding dimension, less layer since it is just a prototype and I have colab notebook with one GPU.

Number of training documents is 174. When I tokenize them and split them into 64 length chunks my training sample size goes up from 174 (documents) to roughly 5 000 (chunks) which is the expected behavior.

If I want to replicate this approach with pytorch iterable dataset and dataloader approach:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import IterableDataset

class ConstantLengthDataset(IterableDataset):

    def __init__(self, tokenizer, dataset, field_name="text", seq_length=CONTEXT_LENGTH,
                 num_of_sequences=174, chars_per_token=characters_per_token):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.concat_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.seq_length = seq_length
        self.input_characters = seq_length * chars_per_token * num_of_sequences
        self.field_name = field_name

    def __iter__(self):
        iterator = iter(self.dataset)
        more_examples = True
        while more_examples:
            buffer, buffer_len = [], 0
            while True:
                if buffer_len >= self.input_characters:
                    m=f"Buffer full: {buffer_len}>={self.input_characters:.0f}"
                    # print(m)
                    break
                try:
                    buffer.append(next(iterator)[self.field_name])
                    buffer_len += len(buffer[-1])
                except StopIteration:
                    iterator = iter(self.dataset)

            all_token_ids = []
            tokenized_inputs = self.tokenizer(buffer, truncation=False)
            for j, tokenized_input in enumerate(tokenized_inputs["input_ids"]):
              all_token_ids.extend(tokenized_input + [self.concat_token_id])
            for i in range(0, len(all_token_ids), self.seq_length):
              input_ids = all_token_ids[i : i + self.seq_length]
              if len(input_ids) == self.seq_length:
                yield torch.tensor(input_ids)
```

and the data loaders:

```
def create_dataloaders(dataset_name):
    train_data = load_from_disk(dataset_name)["train"]
    train_data = train_data.shuffle(seed=args.seed)
    valid_data = load_from_disk(dataset_name)["test"]
    train_dataset = ConstantLengthDataset(tokenizer, train_data,
                                          seq_length=args.seq_length)
    valid_dataset = ConstantLengthDataset(tokenizer, valid_data,
                                          seq_length=args.seq_length)

    train_dataloader=DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=args.train_batch_size)
    eval_dataloader=DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=args.valid_batch_size)
    return train_dataloader, eval_dataloader
```

Since it is an iterable dataset len() is not working. When I iterate through the data:

```
for i, data in enumerate(train_dataloader):
  if i % 10000 == 0:
    print(f"{i}")
```

instead of getting roughly 5000 samples the iteration just goes on, over 9 million. I could not wait for the end of the iteration.

What is going on here?